# Spring Boot with postgres --> HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm new to software dev and doing the [Amigos Spring Boot tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8SGI_XS5OPw) with postgres.

I'm having an error with hikari.

I tried reloading the project, downloading maven locally and setting the maven version to current.  That fixed a pom.xml error I was getting with the spring-boot-maven-plugin.  I still get the pooling error when I run the code tho.

```
---- IntelliJ IDEA coverage runner ---- 
sampling ...
include patterns:
com\.example\.demo\..*
exclude patterns:
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.4)

2021-09-17 14:45:47.414  INFO 21652 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication using Java 16.0.2 on slashruin with PID 21652 (C:\Users\krisp\Downloads\demo\SpringBootTutorial2021\target\classes started by krisp in C:\Users\krisp\Downloads\demo\SpringBootTutorial2021)
2021-09-17 14:45:47.414  INFO 21652 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-09-17 14:45:48.024  INFO 21652 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-09-17 14:45:48.046  INFO 21652 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 6 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-09-17 14:45:48.393  INFO 21652 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8000 (http)
2021-09-17 14:45:48.393  INFO 21652 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-09-17 14:45:48.393  INFO 21652 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.52]
2021-09-17 14:45:48.485  INFO 21652 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-09-17 14:45:48.485  INFO 21652 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1015 ms
2021-09-17 14:45:48.596  INFO 21652 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-09-17 14:45:48.643  INFO 21652 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.32.Final
2021-09-17 14:45:48.738  INFO 21652 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-09-17 14:45:48.810  INFO 21652 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-09-17 14:45:49.926 ERROR 21652 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Something unusual has occurred to cause the driver to fail. Please report this exception.
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:285) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:121) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:176) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1255) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null value for 'password'
    at org.postgresql.shaded.com.ongres.scram.common.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:41) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
    at org.postgresql.shaded.com.ongres.scram.common.util.Preconditions.checkNotEmpty(Preconditions.java:55) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
    at org.postgresql.shaded.com.ongres.scram.client.ScramSession$ServerFirstProcessor.clientFinalProcessor(ScramSession.java:128) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
    at org.postgresql.jre7.sasl.ScramAuthenticator.processServerFirstMessage(ScramAuthenticator.java:147) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:778) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:161) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
    ... 46 common frames omitted

2021-09-17 14:45:49.926  WARN 21652 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Something unusual has occurred to cause the driver to fail. Please report this exception.
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:285) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:121) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:176) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1255) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null value for 'password'
    at org.postgresql.shaded.com.ongres.scram.common.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:41) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
    at org.postgresql.shaded.com.ongres.scram.common.util.Preconditions.checkNotEmpty(Preconditions.java:55) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
    at org.postgresql.shaded.com.ongres.scram.client.ScramSession$ServerFirstProcessor.clientFinalProcessor(ScramSession.java:128) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
    at org.postgresql.jre7.sasl.ScramAuthenticator.processServerFirstMessage(ScramAuthenticator.java:147) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:778) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:161) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
    ... 46 common frames omitted

2021-09-17 14:45:49.926  INFO 21652 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2021-09-17 14:45:50.035  INFO 21652 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-09-17 14:45:50.035  INFO 21652 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-09-17 14:45:50.068  WARN 21652 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-09-17 14:45:50.417  INFO 21652 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8000 (http) with context path ''
2021-09-17 14:45:50.433  INFO 21652 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 3.429 seconds (JVM running for 4.476)
```

Comment: `Null value for 'password'`

Comment: Yes, this is it.  I didn't add a username/password on the application.properties page.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

I did not add the username/password to the application.properties file:

```
server.port=8000
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/student
spring.datasource.username=**USERNAME**
spring.datasource.password=**PASSWORD**
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Comment: I added them, but the error "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: authentication with password failed"; _even though_ I succeed in authenticating on "psql" command line by using the very same password saved in "application.properties" file